# how to use nodejs listen multiple ips?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(80, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

So,if I wanna listen to 192.168.1.100,just like this?

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(80, '127.0.0.1').listen(80,'192.168.1.100');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
var http = require('http');
function handler(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
};
http.createServer(handler).listen(80, '127.0.0.1');
http.createServer(handler).listen(80, '192.168.1.100');
// or listen to both instead - thx @FlashThunder
// http.createServer(handler).listen(80);
```

Answer (score 7):

As http creates socket, you can't assign list of ips to one socket, that's why you need to create separate http objects for every ip, or use `0.0.0.0` (or simply dont define second parameter) to listen on all available ips.